# How to set a global style for styled document in java swing

Tags: java, swing, styles, styleddocument

I have a StyledDocument to which I am adding some style. I want to have some default (global) style that works for all the styles I create. For example a global background for all the style, so that I don't have to specify the `background` for each style.

Here is how I am trying to achieve

```
    public void setUpStyles() {
        parentMSGStyle = historyPane.addStyle("parentmsgstyle", null);
        userNameStyle = historyPane.addStyle("usernamestyle", parentMSGStyle);
        StyleConstants.setBackground(parentMSGStyle, Color.GRAY);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(userNameStyle, Color.BLUE);
    }
```

This does not for now. Only the blue color style is working but not the "GRAY" one.
I am new to StyledDocuments. Please point me to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing this i myself tried and got me confused too. According to the [JAVA DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html#addStyle%28java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.Style%29) of `childStyle = addStyle(String nm, parentStyle)` should show the following behavior:

> Adds a new style into the logical style hierarchy. Style attributes
>   resolve from bottom up so an attribute specified in a child will
>   override an attribute specified in the parent.

As long as we are not setting background color to the child, it should not override the parent style's attribute anyway.

```
StyleConstants.setBackground(parentMSGStyle, Color.GREY);
StyleConstants.setForeground(userNameStyle, Color.BLUE);
```

If we now try to print the document's background color using `document.getBackground(userNameStylee)`, it should print `GRAY` and it does so.
So for unknown reason it is not just doing on the SCREEN. But surprisingly the reverse will work. That is, set the `Forground` to the parentStyle, and Background to the `childStyle`.

```
StyleConstants.setForeground(parentMSGStyle, Color.BLUE);
StyleConstants.setBackground(userNameStyle, Color.GREY);
```

Don't tell me it is not a solution. :)